# Calendar Issue in BlackBerry Java

Tags: blackberry, java-me

```
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 7);
cal.set(Calendar.DATE,13);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2011);
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault()/*getTimeZone("GMT+5:30")*/);
```

I am using the above code to set the date and time , but after setting if i try to retrieve it by  **cal.getTime(**) i get the date and time as

```
sat Aug 13 11:01:01 America/NewYork 2011
```

Comment: Don't flag your questions with "URGENT", please!

Comment: There is no any question or problem definition in your post.

Comment: -1, Question shows that little effort was taken on OP's part to resolve problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `java.util.Calendar` class counts months starting with 0, but days using the actual day of the month. This is an *extremely* frequently asked question -- it trips up nearly everyone the first time they program with the Java `Date` or `Calendar` classes.

Answer (score 3):

Months in the Java Calendar class are numbered 0 to 11, rather than 1 to 12. So subtract 1 from the number of the month you want.

Edited to add: The Calendar class has a number of static variables, including twelve for the months of the year - Calendar.JANUARY (the integer 0), Calendar.FEBRUARY (the integer 1), etc. I'd advise you use those where possible, rather than integers.

Answer (score 3):

Yup, that's exactly what you've set it to.

If you expected it to be July, you need to read the [JavaDoc for `Calendar.MONTH`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH) more closely - it's 0-based:

> Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a calendar-specific value. The first month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0; the last depends on the number of months in a year.

I'd actually urge you to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead, if you can use that on Blackberry - it's a *much* nicer API.